# Cannot load source when run localhost in all browser

Tags: angular, browser

I've already run my angular application, but It's still loading in any browser:

I cannot enter **F12**, or right click in any browser (its ok in other pages)

When I enter **Ctrl + Shift + I** in this page, and select tab source -> it not load my source code here?

(This code is running in the other computer)

What's my problem?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot enter **F12**, or right click in any browser (its ok in other pages), I supect that you have memory leak which take all the memory.

- Infinite loop for example

Comment: Thank you @Wandrille, This is my mistake. Infinite loop is exact my issue

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a stackoverflow and your main thread (the only one you have in JS) hanging.

Try to go to the last point in your code when things work, and then add back parts - this will help you to find where the issue in your code.